# Is there any additional Search & replace components Experts out there?

Tags: delphi, refactoring, components, delphi-2010

I have tried the GExperts Replace Components expert in Delphi 2010 and it seems there is a bug in it.

[GExpert's Replace Components Expert doesn't replace the text in the form file (*.dfm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671119/gexperts-replace-components-expert-doesnt-replace-the-text-in-the-form-file)

Does anyone know of another expert, tools, or method for replace all components in a delphi project in Delphi 2010, in both the unit and the dfm file?

Example: replace all TEdits with TRzEdits, etc.

thanx

Answer (score 0):

If *GExperts' Replace Components expert* deceives you forget about it.

Delphi 2010 has an advanced out-of-the-box refactoring capabilities.

Head to the `Refactoring Overview` topic of the RAD Studio Documentation, you will find plenty of interesting materials.